# Restricting Authorization cookie with forms authentication

Tags: authentication, iis, cookies, web-config

My web application uses form authentication. It is working fine. But when I install 2 instances of the same application as virtual directories, I am able to log into both instances with the same cookie. Is there any way to keep it to a single virtual directory?

Here is my web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAppAuth" loginUrl="~/secured/login" protection="All" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" path="/">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what technology is being used here, but I would guess that the path="/" is used to create the cookie (you could probably use your browser developer tools to make certain). Try setting the path to the root of each webapp /app1 /app2

Comment: Thanks for the path tip. I also had to change the path where the cookie was being set in the MVC layer.
I changed:
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe,"/");
to
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);